# What is the easiest way to restore D365's code base to original?

Tags: dynamics-365-operations, d3fo

How do you restore the code base to fresh installation? I am having some build/sync issues and I would like to undo all my code changes and start over.

Comment: Delete your custom package folder and model folders from existing package in case of over layering  from. AOSService\PackagesLocalDirectory. https://axforce.wordpress.com/2016/01/12/dynamics-ax-7-development-packages-models-projects/ Then Open visual studio, Go to Model Management and Refresh model. Then do a full build and synchronize database.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are asking for the easiest way: Deploy a new environment :)

Jokes aside, what I would do is to clean up the `AOSService\PackagesLocalDirectory` directory and delete the folders that contain your customizations. Alternatively you can copy the contents of the directory from a clean environment of the same version, in case you don't know the names of your customization packages anymore.

From Pradeep's comment: Then Open visual studio, Go to Model Management and Refresh model. Then do a full build and synchronize database.

This should restore your environment back to a clean installation.